# Find a string starting and ending with different substrings, and insert into a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns, `post_content` and `postmeta_value`. I need to select the first instance of a string that begins with `<i>` and ends with `</i>` in the column `post_content`, and then insert that value into `postmeta_value`.

Comment: I think you need to look at the format of your question, I tried to edit and realize that I don't think it looks like what you need. Which character are you looking for?

Comment: I just changed it. I was looking for this (<i>) as the starting character and this (</i>) as the ending character. I replaced them with "hello" and "bye". Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I understand now. I have edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a back slash to escape special characters in the `LIKE` clause. So, if you want to find rows with a column that start and begin with that value, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE post_content LIKE '<i>%</i>';
```

It looks hard to read, so let me decipher for you. The single quotes at the front and back are the terminating quotes for the string you are searching for. Each occurrence of `<i>` and `</i>` is searching for the tag.. The wildcard (%) in the middle will match 0 or more characters, meaning if a row is simply `<i></i>` it will be included as well.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/325f92/1) example.

Once you have that, you can use the select clause in an insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (postmeta_value) SELECT ...
```

Comment: This is the query that I did: INSERT INTO wp_posts (postmeta_value) SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_content LIKE '<i>%</i>' It gave me an error message:  #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: That will not work because you are inserting into one column, but selecting from multiple columns. Change your select to `SELECT post_content FROM...`

Comment: Just tried it again with your revisions, but it said 0 rows were affected. INSERT INTO wp_posts (postmeta_value) SELECT post_content
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_content LIKE '<i>%</i>'

Comment: You're inserting in to the same table, are you sure you're not looking for an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I need to extract everything between <i> and </i> and add it to the other column of the same table.

Comment: The closets I got to figuring it out was doing something similar to this: UPDATE sv_gps 
SET direction = substring(alttext, instr(alttext, 'blick'))
WHERE alttext LIKE '%blick%'    but, it only brought back some of the characters. after <i>.

Comment: I also tried this: UPDATE wp_posts 
SET postmeta_value = substring(post_content, instr(post_content, '<i>%</i>'))
WHERE post_content LIKE '<i>%</i>'

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 1 row, then you could add limit 1 to limit the query to return only 1 row like this.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (postmeta_value) 
SELECT post_content FROM yourTable WHERE post_content LIKE '<i>%</i>' limit 1;
```

Comment: Just tried this, but 0 rows were affected.  INSERT INTO wp_posts (postmeta_value) SELECT post_content
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_content LIKE '<i>%</i>'

Comment: When you try just select statement, does it return you any rows?

Comment: Just ran it, no, it doesn't.

Comment: So, the problem is the select doesn't return what you want. could you please show me some of your data in post_content column, if possible, please?